# How to multiply a data file with another index data file?

Tags: linux, awk, text

I want your help in multiplying my data file with another index data file. Both data files have the same number of rows. But the data file have more than 1000 columns while the index data has only one column. The index file is the factor by which I want to multiply the whole columns of the my data. 
Here is my sample data and the required output below

Data.txt:

```
10  20  30  40  50
20  30  40  50  60
30  40  50  60  70
40  50  60  70  80
50  60  70  80  90
60  70  80  90  100
70  80  90  100 110
80  90  100 110 120
```

index.txt:

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
.
.
.
.
```

Required output file will be

out.txt

```
1   2   3   4   5
4   6   8   10  12
9   12  15  18  21
16  20  24  28  32
25  30  35  40  45
36  42  48  54  60
49  56  63  70  77
64  72  80  88  96
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next}
    {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf("%d\t",$i*a[FNR])}printf("\n")}' index.txt data.txt
```

For `index.txt`, we save value of each line in associative array. Then when proccessing `data.txt` we multiply each fields value with corresponding value in associative array, which is `a[FNR]`.

It works similiar with @devnull's answer but we don't have to hard code file name in our program.

Comment: +1: You can shorten it by doing `awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=$i*a[FNR]}1' OFS='\t' index.txt data.txt`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `awk`.  Read the corresponding line from `index.txt` while reading `data.txt` and multiply every field by the value obtained from the former:

```
awk '{getline f < "index.txt"; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {printf("%d\t",$i*f)} printf("\n")}' data.txt
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
1       2       3       4       5
4       6       8       10      12
9       12      15      18      21
16      20      24      28      32
25      30      35      40      45
36      42      48      54      60
49      56      62      70      77
64      72      80      88      96
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
$ paste index.txt data.txt | 
    awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){printf "%d\t", $1*$(i)}; print "";}' 
1   2   3   4   5   
4   6   8   10  12  
9   12  15  18  21  
16  20  24  28  32  
25  30  35  40  45  
36  42  48  54  60  
49  56  62  70  77  
64  72  80  88  96
```

`paste` will join the corresponding lines of the file, so the index will be `$1` in the `awk` scriptlet which simply goes through each field and multiplies it by the current value of the index.

A similar, if a bit more idiomatic, approach in Perl:

```
$ paste index.txt data.txt | perl -lane 'print join "\t",map{$_*$F[0]}@F[1..$#F]'
```

Comment: That's clever!!!

Answer (score 2):

Simple perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(INDEX,"$ARGV[0]") or die "$@:$!";
open(DATA,"$ARGV[1]") or die "$@:$!";

while (($dline=<DATA>) and ($i=<INDEX>)) {
  chomp($dline, $i);
  for $n (split /\s+/, $dline) {
    printf "%-4d ", $n * $i;
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

.

```
$ perl mult.pl index.txt data.txt
1    2    3    4    5    
4    6    8    10   12   
9    12   15   18   21   
16   20   24   28   32   
25   30   35   40   45   
36   42   48   54   60   
49   56   62   70   77   
64   72   80   88   96
```